# Using an off-by-one buffer overflow can I manipulate EIP to execute code located outside the target program?

Tags: buffer-overflow

*This is for a Computer and Network Security class. I am not asking for the solution, rather just a pointer in the right direction.*

The target program has an off-by-one vulnerability and is compiled such that `ebp` is not pushed on the stack. By attacking the vulnerability, I am able to change the last byte of the `eip` and effectively send the program to any instruction in the program.

My question is, if I place some malicious code in the exploit program (that calls the target program via an `execve`), can I change the `eip` to point to this malicious code, or is the runtime smart enough to know that I am attempting to execute code that is located outside the bounds of the target program and thus, not allow it?

The environment is a stripped down Debian Etch VM with no ASLR etc. The target program has `setuid` set to root, so my goal is to get the target program to execute instructions that pull up a shell (giving me root shell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a *computer*, it *cannot* be smart.

From the point of view of the kernel, memory space is split into pages (typically 4 kB per page). Each page has *access rights*, like "can be written to", "can be read", "can be executed" or "cannot be accessed / not here". The kernel will not mind in any way as long as you jump into a page which is marked as "can be executed". If you alter only the least significant byte of `eip`, you will fall into the same page than the original caller, so the jump *will* be allowed. Of course, if you jump into bytes which do not make sense as instructions, things will go sour pretty fast...

(Note: on 32-bit x86 CPU, with usual operating systems, there may be no difference between "can read" and "can execute" for pages; it is a quirk of the [Memory Management Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) used in the early 32-bit x86 CPU.)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I'm definitely on the right path with the exploit.